# MATLAB GPU-enabled function?

Tags: gpu, matlab, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

Is there a way for me to find out whether the functions I'm using in a MATLAB script are GPU-enabled? There does not seem to be a comprehensive list (though see this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/supported-functions.html) for a list of image processing GPU-enabled functions), but only documentation notes that say there are "hundreds of [GPU-enabled] functions in MATLAB and other toolboxes run automatically on GPU" ([link1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-matlab-functions-on-a-gpu.html), [link2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gpuarray.html), [link3](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/gpu-programming-in-matlab.html), [link4](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/supported-functions.html)).

More generally, MATLAB requires you to create an array on the GPU (a "gpuArray" object), but it is important to use a function which supports GPU ([link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gpuarray.html)). I could of course simply try creating a gpuArray and then passing it into the functions in question and measuring computing time differences. But I would like to know *ex-ante* whether this should provide improved computing speed.

Thank you,